# Clear activity stack in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-stack

I have a `LoginActivity` as my launcher screen. And `SettingsActivity` as my `fifth screen`.

I have a `logout button` in settings screen. `On clcik` of this button, how can i go to `Screen-1 (i.e LoginActivity)` by clearing all remaining activities `(i.e 2nd, 3rd, 4th)` from activity stack?

Note : i have finished `LoginActivity` but not remaining activities. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can declare Login to be singleTask, i think this should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, set an onclick on your logout button and then add this to your intent:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, login.class);

    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    startActivity(newIntent);
    finish();
```

This should clear your entire stack above login.class

And if you're feeling real fun today, add

```
    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Which will get rid of that annoying "show the android homescreen" issue on the S3